# Search Through Multidimensional Array for value and return all subarray values and it's key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to search for a keyword in an array of arrays and upon success return all info associated with all of the arrays that contain it.

Here is what the array looks like

```
Array
(
[#10-CH-L/W] => Array
    (
        [0] => 278.00
        [1] => HIGH COLLAR LOCK WASHER
        [2] => NUTBLT
    )

[#16S-NUTS] => 6.00
[#16S-SLEEVES] => 13.00
[#16SS-NUTS] => 1.00
[#16SS-SLEEVES] => 4.00
[#20S-NUTS] => 11.00
[#20S-SLEEVES] => 14.00
[#20SS-NUTS] => .00
[#20SS-SLEEVES] => .00
[#400-CLAMP] => Array
    (
        [0] => .00
        [1] => DIXON HOSE CLAMP-3-1/2" OD
        [2] => FITTST
    )

[#8S-SLEEVES] => 5.00
[-006-BN70] => Array
    (
        [0] => 181.00
        [1] => O-RING 1/8 X 1/4 X 1/16
        [2] => SEALS 
    )

[-006-VT75] => Array
    (
        [0] => .00
        [1] => O-RING 1/8 X 1/4 X 1/16
        [2] => SEALS 
    )
```

I found a similar question on here and modified/attempted the code, but it only returns one match from the array and puts the key for it into an array.  This would be fine if it returned the keys for ALL of the associated arrays. *edit* it appears the loops is only finding the first occurrence of $id and then stopping

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
               foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                   if ($val[2] === $id) {
                      $keyarray[] = $key;

                       return $keyarray;
                   }

               }    
               return null;
            }

            $id = searchForId('SEALS', $multi-array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function searchForId($id, $array) {
          $keyarray = [];
           foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
               if (isset($val[2]) && $val[2] === $id) {
                  array_push( $keyarray, $key);
               }
           }    
           return $keyarray;
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result with this, though the push makes sense.  I think there's something wrong with the way it is searching through the array.  when I print it $key as the loop is happening I only get the last result too, which happens to be the very last value in the array.

Comment: actually, it appears to be finding only the first occurrence of $id and stopping right after.

Comment: @LeviBesaw I updated my code try this. Bcoz of second array element doesn't  3 elements. So thats make error

Comment: Thank you!! that worked perfectly.  Now I just have to grab print out the data associated with each of those keys.  I'll update with that. You're amazing Sivabalan!

Comment: Glad its helped you

Answer (score 0):

@Sivabalan's answer was just what I needed.  I just added one piece to get the code spitting out the data associated with each sub-array. I've been lurking for years. What was I thinking?

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
                    $keyarray = array();
                       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                            if (isset($val[2]) && $val[2] === $id) {
                                 array_push( $keyarray, $key);
                                 echo "$key | $val[0] | $val[1] | $val[2]";
                                }

                           }
                            return $keyarray;                  
               }    



            $id = searchForId('needles', $haystack);
```